# Getting time slots from Datetime column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which reads like this:

```
Datetime            Transaction        Item
3/16/2020 9:58        1                 X
3/17/2020 10:05       2                 Y
3/18/2016 14:48       3                 Z
```

What I need is Datetime column to be converted to weekday and one hour time slots? For eg:

```
Weekday              TimeSlot        Transaction        Item
1                      9-10              1              X
2                     10-11             2              Y
3                     14-15             3              Z
```

I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Datetime'].dt.dayofweek
df['Hour'] = df['Datetime'].dt.hour
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df['slot'] = df.groupby(df.Datetime.dt.hour//1).ngroup()+1
```

Is there a simple way to do it? I am using Python-3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what weekday is doing here. Isn't it just extract the time and add one hour?

```
hours = df['Datetime'].dt.hour

df['TimeSlot'] = hours.astype(str) + "-" + hours.add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
             Datetime  Transaction Item TimeSlot
0 2016-10-30 09:58:00            1    X     9-10
1 2016-10-30 10:05:00            2    Y    10-11
2 2016-10-30 14:48:00            3    Z    14-15
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem for weekday, once you have converted the `Datetime` column to a true Timestamp type:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])
df['Weekday'] = dt.dt.dayofweek
```

The slot is `_hour_-_hour+1_` except when you are about to change day where it becomes `23-0`.

You could do:

```
start_hour = dt.dt.hour
end_hour = pd.Series(np.where(start_hour == 23, 0, start_hour +1),
                     index=start_hour.index)
df['Slot'] = start_hour.astype(str) + '-' + end_hour.astype(str)
```